# Changing MTU constantly

Tags: linux, mtu

I am building a custom layer 1 (using rf radios).  I am building a tap/tun solution running on Linux on both sides of the radio link so I can get internet over my link.  Due to the nature of radio link (packet length etc), my MTU is fairly small (500 or less sometimes).  But it's also changing with time and signal conditions.  Is it bad / will programs complain if an interface has an MTU that is constantly changing?  Is this bad practice?

If so should I be handling this internally myself? For instance if Linux think's the MTU is 1000 bytes but my link only supports 500 bytes, should I just do the work to glue 2 packets together myself to ensure the MTU is changing less often?  Thanks

Comment: It is certainly less than ideal, why don't you just set your Linux interfaces to an MTU size that is going to be safe like 450 octets MTU? Or is that not possible in your situation?

Comment: Leaving it at 450 is possible but it will reduce performance when the actual internal mtu is larger.  I expect that in the final product the MTU will ramp up slowly after a period.  Maybe I can "debounce" changing the mtu to no more than once per minute?

Comment: With an MTU that small, you will run into problems with some protocols, e.g. IPv6 _requires a minimum MTU of 1280 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I found out that ssh will not connect with a small MTU as well

Comment: If you want to run IP on your link, the minimum IPv4 MTU is 576, and the minimum IPv6 MTU is 1280. If you cannot meet those, or if the MTU changes, then you are going to need to do some custom work that is off-topic here.

Comment: 576 bytes is the minimum MSS, not the minimum MTU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP doesn't handle varying MTUs well. Typically each time the MTU reduces there will be another round of path MTU discovery and when the MTU increases again the sending host will have no way to discover that fact.

Plus if you want to support IPv6 you will need a MTU of at least 1280 bytes. Theoretically IPv4 should support MTUs down to 68 bytes but operation with such small MTUs will be highly inefficient and is unlikely to be well-tested.

So yes if your underlying link has a short and variable maximum packet size you should perform your own fragmentation and reassembly below the IP layer. Once you are doing that you may as well make the IP MTU 1500 bytes.